# Does Azure AD B2C support multiple user pools within the directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c, auth0-connection

I'm creating a multi tenant application where each user email address can exist independently in one or more tenants.

So bob@test.com can register for both TenantA.com and register again for TenantB.com. He will exist twice as 2 separate entities.

AWS supports this concept though multiple *User Pools* per account

Auth0 supports this concept though multiple *Connections* per account

Does Azure AD B2C have a comparable offering, and if so where is it documented. There seem to be a number of workarounds available, but I've been unable to find any documentation to support this scenario directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications) and add multiple B2C tenants as [Azure AD external Identity Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=applications) so that a user can select which tenant they want to login. Each B2C tenant would host a local user with the shared email.

Comment: This might be a problem because ad b2c has its limit for tenant set at 30. But under 30 this works perfectly fine.